# If statement with negative values

Tags: c++, strcmp

In an if statement like this:

```
    if(strcmp(str1,str2))
```

strcmp() can return a negative value, and if it does, does the if statement consider it to be TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, the `if` statement treats any *nonzero* value as true. A negative value is not zero, so it will be considered true. The following two statements are equivalent:

```
if (strcmp(str1, str2))

if (strcmp(str1, str2) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `strcmp` function when used with an if statement can lead to some very unreadable code. The following statement says to call `foo` if and only if `str1` is *different* than `str2`.

```
if (strcmp(str1, str2)) foo();
```

Some would argue this is somewhat unexpected and unreadable, but it's due to the fact that `strcmp` is not really meant to be used this way as it does not return a `bool`. If you check out this great [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) you'll see that it returns an integral value which is meant to indicate the relationship between the strings. `strcmp` can tell you much more than simply whether or not two strings are the same. According to the reference `strcmp` returns:

- 0 if both strings are equal
- A positive value if the first character that does not match has a greater value in `str1` than in `str2`
- A negative value if the first character that does not match has a greater value in `str2` than in `str1`

Because an if statement will coerce any non-zero integer value into a boolean value of `true` the if statement `if (strcmp(str1, str2)) foo()` will always interpret `true` and execute `foo`, *except* when `str1` and `str2` are equal (in which case the if statement will interpret `false` and foo will *not* be executed).

The more common way to use strcmp with an if statement is to combine your call to strcmp with a binary comparison within the if statement, testing against an integral value:

```
if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0) foo(); // foo executed iff str1 and str2 are equal
if (strcmp(str1, str2) != 0) foo(); // foo executed iff str1 and str2 are not equal
```

You might also use `strcmp` with an if statement to sort strings, strcmp is ideal for this because it returns based on the first unmatching character of the string. You could use it with something like the following (untested code):

```
bool swapped = false;
do {
    for (i = 1; i < numStrings; i++) {
        if (strcmp(str[i-1], str[i]) > 0) {
            swap(i-1, i);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

When an integer value is converted to a Boolean value, 0 is false and any other value is true.

Answer (score 0):

C converts any non-zero value to `true` and only zero is `false`.

Note that `if(strcmp(str1, str2))` is NEARLY always "wrong". You either want one of:

- `if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)` to detect that two strings are equal
- `if (strcmp(str1, str2) > 0)` to detect that `str1 > str2`
- `if (strcmp(str1, str2)  < 0)` to detect that `str1 < str2`

The only reason for `if(strcmp(str1, str2))` is for detecting that `str1` is different from `str2` - which is nearly always not what you want.

And of coruse, in C++, you probably shouldn't be using `strcmp` at all - since you have `std::string` that you can just write what you want as a comparison, e.g. `if (str1 > str2)` or `if (str1 != str2)`, and it's immediately obvious to most people what it means without further questions.

Comment: Using strcmp() to see if two strings are different is a perfectly valid and common thing to do.  (although when using C++ rather than C, using std::string would be preferred)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Sure it's a valid combination. But I find that I've made the mistake of "forgetting" the `==0`, and I've seen PLENTY of questions on here (and other places) where the question is "Why isn't `strcmp` working?" based on not comparing to zero in some way.